# How to access Window variables from LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, pre-chat, embedded-services

I'm trying to dynamically do matching on an Embedded Service but using a LWC for the prechat page. I've been following a few sources and its mostly been working fine, but when trying to get window.embedded_svc (the Embedded Service's settings) from an LWC it always returns Null. Is there a way I can retrieve it to edit from an LWC?

```
import BasePrechat from 'lightningsnapin/basePrechat';
import { api, track } from 'lwc';

export default class Prechat extends BasePrechat {
    @api prechatFields;
    @api backgroundImgURL;
    @track fields;
    @track namelist;

    /**
     * Set the button label and prepare the prechat fields to be shown in the form.
     */
    connectedCallback() {
        console.log('embedded_svc', 'connected', window.embedded_svc);

        this.fields = this.prechatFields.map(field => {
            const { label, name, value, required, maxLength } = field;

            return { label, value, name, required, maxLength };
        });
        this.namelist = this.fields.map(field => field.name);
    }

    /**
     * Focus on the first input after this component renders.
     */
    renderedCallback() {
        this.template.querySelector("lightning-input").focus();
        console.log('embedded_svc', 'rendered', window.embedded_svc);
    }

    /**
     * On clicking the 'Start Chatting' button, send a chat request.
     */
    handleStartChat() {
        this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input").forEach(input => {
            this.fields[this.namelist.indexOf(input.name)].value = input.value;
        });

        if (this.validateFields(this.fields).valid) {
            this.startChat(this.fields);
        } else {
            // Error handling if fields do not pass validation.
        }
    }
}
```